# Animations are stuck/frozen after cancel (onPause) and start (onResume)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I am trying to animate 3 icons in my `Activity` using `ObjectAnimator`.
The animation itself works fine but when I test it by locking and unlocking the screen, the animation freezes/gets stuck, usually after the second time locking and unlocking the screen. Once it is stuck, locking & unlocking does not release/resume animations.

I tried to cancel and start the `Animators` in `onPause()` and `onResume()` respectively, but it doesn't seem to work. Also tried many other suggestions on Stack Overflow but couldn't find a proper solution to this issue.

**Class responsible for animations:**

```kotlin
class MyAnimator(views: List<View>) {

    private var animators = listOf<Animator>()

    init {
        animators = views.map { createAnimator(it) }

    }

    fun startAnimations() {
        animators.forEach {
            it.start()
        }
    }

    fun cancelAnimations() {
        animators.forEach {
            it.cancel()
        }
    }

    private fun createAnimator(view: View): Animator {
        val jumpAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", 40f, 360f).apply {
            repeatCount = INFINITE
            repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
        }

        val rotateAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 360f).apply {
            repeatCount = INFINITE
            repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
        }

        return AnimatorSet().apply {
            duration = Random.nextLong(1200, 1800)
            playTogether(jumpAnimation, rotateAnimation)
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```kotlin
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var animator: MyAnimator
    private var icons = listOf<ImageView>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)
        gameIcons = listOf(firstIconIV, secondIconIV, thirdIconIV)
        animator = MyAnimator(gameIcons)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        animator.cancelAnimations()
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        animator.startAnimations()
    }
}
```